# Why do class objects have access to instance modules in Kernel module?

Tags: ruby, module

I'm learning Ruby and recently discovered something I didn't quite understand. When mixing in modules into Classes, a class Object can not access the modules instance methods.

```
module Swimmable
  def swim
    puts 'can swim'
  end
end

class Fish
  include Swimmable
end

Fish.swim
```

Result is `undefined method 'swim' for Fish:Class (NoMethodError)` which is expected

However if the instance method is defined in the Kernel module, I can access it using a class object and an instance object.

```
module Kernel
  def swim
    puts 'can swim'
  end
end

class Fish; end

Fish.swim # => can swim
Fish.new.swim # => can swim
```

What makes the class object `Fish` able to access instance methods in the Kernel module?

Comment: If you want `Swimmable` available to your class object, write `extend Swimmable` in `Fish`. This way you don't need to define the module in `Kernel`. Further reading search term: _singleton class_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html):

> The Kernel module is included by class Object, so its methods are available in every Ruby object.

Both `Fish` instances and the `Fish` class itself are Objects, so they have all the methods defined in `Kernel`.

In the first case you get the error because including `Swimmable` in `Fish` will make `Swimmable` members available on instances of `Fish`, but not on the class itself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it just gave me a deeper level of understanding `Class` and `Object`. Basically any instance method in Class Object is available to every `Class object` and `instance object`.